# How to call notification in OnReceive () method, of AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, timepicker

I have a **AlarmManager** calling a **ReceiverManager** (the **AlarmManager** creates alarm and **ReceiverManager** treats, displaying a toast). I also have a notification (ready-class) and tried to call her by the Intent class method onReceiver ReceiverManager but nothing happened.

How to implement an intent q call a class that extends Activity? It is always necessary that it extend **BroadcastReceiver**?

Comment: You get a Context in onRecieve.  Use that as the context for your calls.

Comment: @Override
 public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
  

 }well?